# Do I need to call EasyTracker.getInstance().setContext in Fragment

Tags: android, google-analytics

I have an `Activity`, which is going to switch among various different `Fragment` views from time to time. In my `Activity` code, let's say I have

```
  @Override
  public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    ... // The rest of your onStart() code.
    EasyTracker.getInstance().activityStart(this); // Add this method.
  }

  @Override
  public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    ... // The rest of your onStop() code.
    EasyTracker.getInstance().activityStop(this); // Add this method.
  }
```

In every `Fragment` code, do I need to have?

```
EasyTracker.getInstance().setContext(this.getActivity());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I need to call EasyTracker.getInstance().setContext in Fragment?

Not necessarily. It depends on where you are using the EasyTracker in your Fragment. If your Activity's `onStart()` method has been called before you use the EasyTracker, then you will be fine and EasyTracker will use the Activity's Context.

However, if your Fragment uses the EasyTracker before the Activity's `onStart()` finishes (for example in `onCreateView()` or the Fragment's `onStart()`), then the EasyTracker will not have  a Context yet and you will get an exception.

Comment: What about FragmentActivities?  Does your suggestion apply there?

Comment: Assuming you are still calling `activityStart()` in the FragmentActivity's `onStart()`, yes. In short, you don't need to set the Context if the EasyTracker already has a Context. `startActivity()` is one of a few methods that sets a Context.